# Can Java display a dialog without changing the active window?

Tags: java, swing, window

I'd like to display a modal (progress) dialog above a `Frame`, even if that `Frame` isn't the active window.  However, displaying a dialog causes it or its owner to become the active window.  Is there a way to display a dialog without it or its owner becoming the active window -- specifically, on a Windows platform?

The reason I'd like to do this is: periodically my `Frame` refreshes itself and displays its modal progress dialog while refreshing.  Right now my application only refreshes while it's the active window.

SSCCE, since people are asking for it:

```
Frame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible( true );
// 30 seconds later (using a Timer/TimerTask)
Dialog dialog = new JDialog( frame, ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL );
dialog.setVisible( true );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a modal dialog.

However the following works for a non-modal dialog:

```
dialog.setFocusableWindowState( false );
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.setFocusableWindowState( true );
```

When the dialog displays it will not have focus, but if you click on it, it will gain focus. You could try this on a modal dialog to see what happens.

Comment: The first two lines also work for modal dialogs (at least on Vista).  I haven't tried other permutations yet, but this is good enough!